# java deep copy through copy constructor

Tags: java, copy-constructor, deep-copy

What I would like to do is to define a copy constructor which
takes A as an argument and it initializes the new A to be a deep
copy of argument A

```
public class A<E extends Comparable<? super E>> implements B<E> 
{
    private A a;
    private E[] hArray;

    // What I tried .... my copy constructor

    public A(A other)
    {
         this.a = other;  // deep copy
    }
}
```

Is this the right way of doing deep copy through copy constructor??

Comment: Just to clarify, do you want 'this.a' to be a deep copy of 'other', or do you want 'this' to be a deep copy of 'other'?

Comment: hm new A to be a deep copy of argument A..

Comment: Ok, then my answer below still stands.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's not a deep copy. You are just storing the reference to the other object.

Try this:

```
public A(A other) {
    if(other.a != null) {
        this.a = new A(other.a);
    }
    if(other.hArray != null) {
        this.hArray = new E[other.hArray.length];
        for(int index = 0; index < other.hArray.length; index++) {
            this.hArray[index] = other.hArray[index].clone();
        }
    }
}
```

This assumes that E also has a copy constructor that performs a deep copy. Plus I just noticed that E is a generic, so my code might not work correctly for that (but the idea is there).

Comment: Yeah, I think the best way might be to put the restriction that `E` implements `Cloneable` if possible... then you could just go `this.hArray[index] = other.hArray[index].clone();` - but of course that doesn't guarantee a deep copy...

Comment: All Java arrays implement a public `clone()`, you could use that to initially copy `hArray`.

Comment: But that wouldn't be deep copying the E objects. I think @Jeff got it right with cloning the individual elements. I've edited my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can't just assign if you want a deep copy - that's not what deep copy means. You'd need to go:

```
public A(A other)
{
    if(other != null) {
        this.a = new A(other.a);  // deep copy
    } else {
        this.a = null;
    }
}
```

That's recursive copying, and you could wind up with all kinds of infinite loops, though. Also, you'd need to deep copy `E` somehow, and those generics are kind of boggling my mind, so I won't try to speculate on how you might do that.